# Rust complains that BitOr isn't implemented for a HashSet when performing a union, docs state it should be

Tags: rust, hashset

Minimum example:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

struct Something {
    a: HashSet<Point>,
    b: HashSet<Point>
}

impl Something {
    fn TEST(&self) {
        let new = self.a | self.b;
    }
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Hash, Copy, Clone)]
struct Point {
    x: usize,
    y: usize
}
```

Check it [on the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=622f89dc543d72d506ed3a1fcb0b9fc9). If you try and compile this code, Rust will complain with `error[E0369]: no implementation for std::collections::HashSet<Point> | std::collections::HashSet<Point>`.

But according to [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#impl-BitOr%3C%26%27_%20HashSet%3CT%2C%20S%3E%3E) for HashSet, at least according to my understanding,  the `BitOr` trait should be implemented for a HashSet, where `T: Eq + Hash + Clone`, which `Point` clearly is here. So what's actually going on, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a closer look at the [implemention of `BitOr` for `HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/collections/hash/set.rs.html#991-1021):

```
impl<T, S> BitOr<&HashSet<T, S>> for &HashSet<T, S>
where
   ...
```

`BitOr` is only implemented for references to `HashSet`s, not for owned values.

Re-writing your implementation for `Something::TEST` as follows will compile as expected.

```
impl Something {
    fn TEST(&self) {
        let new = &self.a | &self.b;
    }
}
```

Note that this uses references to `self.a` and `self.b`.

---

The fact that operations like bitwise-or are only implemented for references to containers instead of for the the container types themselves may seem unexpected at first, but it makes perfect sense when you think about their expected ownership semantics. The signature of `bitor` is `fn bitor(self, rhs: T)`, which takes ownership of both `self` and `rhs`. If `BitOr` (or any other binary operator trait) were implemented directory a type that isn't `Copy`, then it would be taking ownership of the arguments to `|`. Having `a | b` resulting in either a or b being moved would be rather unexpected. As such, the standard library only implements binary operators for references to collections (which are `Copy`able) rather than on collection values themselves.

Comment: That's pretty weird, especially given that it returns an owned value. But yeah, this is the solution. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @naiveai Bear in mind that the signature of `bitor` is `fn bitor(self, rhs: T)`, i.e. it takes ownership of `self` and `rhs`. If we implement `BitOr` (or any other binary operator trait) for a type that isn't `Copy`, we would be taking ownership of values whenever we used `|`.  Having `a | b` resulting in either `a` or `b` being moved would be rather unexpected. As such, the standard library only implements binary operators for references to collections (which are `Copy`able`) rather than on collection values themselves.